# How to wait until Kubernetes assigned an external IP to a LoadBalancer service?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

Creating a [Kubernetes LoadBalancer](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/services.html#type-loadbalancer) returns immediatly (ex: `kubectl create -f ...` or  `kubectl expose svc NAME --name=load-balancer --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer`).

I know a manual way to wait in shell:

```
external_ip=""
while [ -z $external_ip ]; do
    sleep 10
    external_ip=$(kubectl get svc load-balancer --template="{{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress}}{{.ip}}{{end}}")
done
```

This is however not ideal:

- Requires at least 5 lines Bash script.
- Infinite wait even in case of error (else requires a timeout which increases a lot line count).
- Probably not efficient; could use `--wait` or `--wait-once` but using those the command never returns.

Is there a better way to wait until a service *external IP* (aka *LoadBalancer Ingress IP*) is set or failed to set?

Answer (score 14):

Just to add to the answers here, the best option right now is to use a bash script. For convenience, I've put it into a single line that includes exporting an environmental variable.

**Command to wait and find Kubernetes service endpoint**

```
bash -c 'external_ip=""; while [ -z $external_ip ]; do echo "Waiting for end point..."; external_ip=$(kubectl get svc NAME_OF_YOUR_SERVICE --template="{{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress}}{{.ip}}{{end}}"); [ -z "$external_ip" ] && sleep 10; done; echo "End point ready-" && echo $external_ip; export endpoint=$external_ip'
```

I've also modified your script so it only executes a wait if the ip isn't available. The last bit will export an environment variable called "endpoint"

**Bash Script to Check a Given Service**

Save this as `check-endpoint.sh` and then you can execute `$sh check-endpoint.sh SERVICE_NAME`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Pass the name of a service to check ie: sh check-endpoint.sh staging-voting-app-vote
# Will run forever...
external_ip=""
while [ -z $external_ip ]; do
  echo "Waiting for end point..."
  external_ip=$(kubectl get svc $1 --template="{{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress}}{{.ip}}{{end}}")
  [ -z "$external_ip" ] && sleep 10
done
echo 'End point ready:' && echo $external_ip
```

**Using this in a Codefresh Step**

I'm using this for a Codefresh pipeline and it passes a variable $endpoint when it's done.

```
  GrabEndPoint:
    title: Waiting for endpoint to be ready
    image: codefresh/plugin-helm:2.8.0
    commands:
      - bash -c 'external_ip=""; while [ -z $external_ip ]; do echo "Waiting for end point..."; external_ip=$(kubectl get svc staging-voting-app-vote --template="{{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress}}{{.ip}}{{end}}"); [ -z "$external_ip" ] && sleep 10; done; echo "End point ready-" && echo $external_ip; cf_export endpoint=$external_ip'
```

Comment: `kubectl get svc $1 --output="jsonpath={.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}"` worked for me

Comment: `.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname` if you're running your k8s on AWS or another provider where the LoadBalancer is not backed by IP but an DNS name

Answer (score 3):

This is little bit tricky by working solution:

```sh
kubectl get service -w load-balancer -o 'go-template={{with .status.loadBalancer.ingress}}{{range .}}{{.ip}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{.err}}{{end}}' 2>/dev/null | head -n1
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is not the solution that you're looking for but at least it has less lines of code:

```
until [ -n "$(kubectl get svc load-balancer -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')" ]; do
    sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 3):

We had [a similar problem on AWS EKS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108500/4964553) and wanted to have a one-liner for that to use in our CI pipelines. We simply ["watched" the output of a command until a particular string is observed and then exit](https://superuser.com/a/375331/497608) using the `until` loop:

```
until kubectl get service/<service-name> --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done
```

To avoid an infinite loop you could enhance it [using timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58759974/4964553) ([`brew install coreutils` on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70109348/4964553)):

```
timeout 10s bash -c 'until kubectl get service/<service-name> --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done'
```

Getting the ip after that is easy using:

```
kubectl get service/<service-name> --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'
```

or when using a service like AWS EKS you most likely have `hostname` populated instead of `ip`:

```
kubectl get service/<service-name> --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}'
```

**Sidenote (Update 03.2023)**: `kubectl wait` would be ideal, but will [not be able to wait on arbitrary jsonpath](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/80828) until `v1.23` (see [this PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/105776)). BUT even from 1.24 on we seem [to not be able to use `kubectl wait`](https://megamorf.gitlab.io/2022/02/16/kubectl-wait-on-arbitrary-json-path/) since `.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0]` is a list, which is not supported by the `kubectl wait` jsonpath implementation. So the command `kubectl wait service/<service-name> --for=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}'=ingress` throws one of the following errors (see also [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73695734/4964553)):

```
error: jsonpath wait format must be --for=jsonpath='{.status.readyReplicas}'=3
error: jsonpath leads to a nested object or list which is not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a "failed to set" condition because we will retry it forever.  A failure might have been a transient error in the cloud provider or a quota issue that gets resolved over the course of hours or days, or any number of things.  The only failure comes from "how long are you willing to wait?" - which only you can know.

We don't have a general "wait for expression" command because it ends up being arbitrarily complex and you're better off just coding that in a real language.  Ergo the bash loop above.  We could do better about having a 'watch' command, but it's still a timeout in the end.

Comment: What does "fail" mean?  That the overall system will stop trying?  Why? Should it then mark the Service as failed?  I am not clear what you are trying to accomplish - is it that you don't know if the environment actually supports LB?  Or that you expect a cloud provider to fail?  Regardless - you have a way to do it already, you just don't like looping :)

Comment: fail means exit 1 if no external IP has been assigned within X seconds. Yes I don't like to make a script to deploy. Deployment should be as simple as possible to avoid bug in my script to cause serious damage as one script per project is a lot more likely to have bugs than a common script/feature for all Kuberentes projects.

Comment: I would not object to a general-purpose "wait for condition, with optional timeout" command in kubectl, but generalizing it is complicated and likely to take a while.  You'll get results much faster by wrapping it in a shell loop.

Answer (score 0):

Really just a clean-up of @Dan Garfield's working example; My OCD wouldn't let this slide. In this case:

- on GCP
- requesting an *internal* lb
- with an annotation in a service definition

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: yo
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
    # external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: vault.stage.domain.tld.
...
```

*NOTE: I've only been able to get external-dns to associate names to public IP addresses.*

---

This has been scripted to accept a few arguments, now it's a library; example:

```
myServiceLB=$1
while true; do                                                                     
    successCond="$(kubectl get svc "$myServiceLB" \                                
        --template="{{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress}}{{.ip}}{{end}}")"        
    if [[ -z "$successCond" ]]; then                                               
        echo "Waiting for endpoint readiness..."                                   
        sleep 10                                                                   
    else                                                                           
        sleep 2                                                                    
        export lbIngAdd="$successCond"                                             
        pMsg """
            The Internal LoadBalancer is up!
        """                                                                        
        break                                                                      
    fi                                                                             
done
```

Later, `$lbIngAdd` can be used to set records. Seems like `-o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[*].ip}"` would work as well; whatever works.

Thanks for getting us started Dan :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic bash function to ***watch with timeout***, for any regexp in the output of a given command:

```
function watch_for() {
  CMD="$1" # Command to watch. Variables should be escaped \$
  REGEX="$2" # Pattern to search
  ATTEMPTS=${3:-10} # Timeout. Default is 10 attempts (interval of second)
  COUNT=0;

  echo -e "# Watching for /$REGEX/ during $ATTEMPTS seconds, on the output of command:\n# $CMD"
  until eval "$CMD" | grep -m 1 "$REGEX" || [[ $COUNT -eq $ATTEMPTS ]]; do
    echo -e "$(( COUNT++ ))... \c"
    sleep 1
  done
  if [[ $COUNT -eq $ATTEMPTS ]]; then
    echo "# Limit of $ATTEMPTS attempts has exceeded."
    return 1
  fi
  return 0
}
```

And here's how I used it to **wait until a worker node gets an external IP** (which took more than a minute):

```
$ watch_for "kubectl get nodes -l node-role.kubernetes.io/worker -o wide | awk '{print \$7}'" \
"[0-9]" 100
```

`0... 1... 2... 3... .... 63... 64...` **3.22.37.41**