# kubectl wait for Service on AWS EKS to expose Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) address reported in .status.loadBalancer.ingress field

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

As [the kubernetes.io docs state about a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer):

> On cloud providers which support external load balancers, setting the
> type field to LoadBalancer provisions a load balancer for your
> Service. The actual creation of the load balancer happens
> asynchronously, and information about the provisioned balancer is
> published in the Service's `.status.loadBalancer` field.

On AWS Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) a an AWS Load Balancer is provisioned that load balances network traffic ([see AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html) & [the example project on GitHub provisioning a EKS cluster with Pulumi](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks)). Assuming we have a `Deployment` ready with the selector `app=tekton-dashboard` (it's the [default Tekton dashboard you can deploy as stated in the docs](https://tekton.dev/docs/dashboard/#installation)), a `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` defined in `tekton-dashboard-service.yml` could look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual
spec:
  selector:
    app: tekton-dashboard
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9097
  type: LoadBalancer
```

If we create the Service in our cluster with `kubectl apply -f tekton-dashboard-service.yml -n tekton-pipelines`, the AWS ELB get's created automatically:

[image]

There's only one problem: The `.status.loadBalancer` field is populated with the `ingress[0].hostname` field asynchronously and is therefore not available immediately. We can check this, if we run the following commands together:

```
kubectl apply -f tekton-dashboard-service.yml -n tekton-pipelines && \
kubectl get service/tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual -n tekton-pipelines --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}'
```

The output will be an empty field:

```
{}%
```

So if we want to run this setup in a CI pipeline for example (e.g. [GitHub Actions, see the example project's workflow `provision.yml`](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks/blob/main/.github/workflows/provision.yml)), **we need to somehow wait until the `.status.loadBalancer` field got populated with the AWS ELB's hostname.** How can we achieve this using `kubectl wait`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;**

[Prior to Kubernetes `v1.23`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/105776) it's not possible using `kubectl wait`, but using `until` together with `grep` like this:

```
until kubectl get service/tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual -n tekton-pipelines --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done
```

or even enhance the command [using timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58759974/4964553) ([`brew install coreutils` on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70109348/4964553)) to prevent the command from running infinitely:

```
timeout 10s bash -c 'until kubectl get service/tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual -n tekton-pipelines --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done'
```

**Problem with kubectl wait & the solution explained in detail**

As stated in [this so Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114851/kubectl-wait-for-service-to-get-external-ip) and the kubernetes issues [kubectl wait unable to not wait for service ready #80828](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/80828#issuecomment-517555879) & [kubectl wait on arbitrary jsonpath #83094](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/80828) using `kubectl wait` for this isn't possible in current Kubernetes versions right now.

The main reason is, that `kubectl wait` assumes that the `status` field of a Kubernetes resource queried with `kubectl get service/xyz --output=yaml` contains a `conditions` list. Which a `Service` doesn't have. Using jsonpath here would be a solution and will be possible from Kubernetes `v1.23` on (see [this merged PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/105776)). But until this version is broadly available in managed Kubernetes clusters like EKS, we need another solution. And it should also be available as "one-liner" just as a `kubectl wait` would be.

A good starting point could be this superuser answer about ["watching" the output of a command until a particular string is observed and then exit](https://superuser.com/a/375331/497608):

```
until my_cmd | grep "String Im Looking For"; do : ; done
```

If we use this approach together with a `kubectl get` we can craft a command which will wait until the field `ingress` gets populated into the `status.loadBalancer` field in our `Service`:

```
until kubectl get service/tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual -n tekton-pipelines --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done
```

This will wait until the `ingress` field got populated and then print out the AWS ELB address (e.g. via using `kubectl get service tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual -n tekton-pipelines --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}'` thereafter):

```
$ until kubectl get service/tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual -n tekton-pipelines --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done
{"ingress":[{"hostname":"a74b078064c7d4ba1b89bf4e92586af0-18561896.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com"}]}
```

Now we have a one-liner command that behaves just like a `kubectl wait` for our `Service` to become available through the AWS Loadbalancer. We can double check if this is working with the following commands combined (be sure to delete the Service using `kubectl delete service/tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual -n tekton-pipelines` before you execute it, because otherwise the Service incl. the AWS LoadBalancer already exists):

```
kubectl apply -f tekton-dashboard-service.yml -n tekton-pipelines && \
until kubectl get service/tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual -n tekton-pipelines --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done && \
kubectl get service tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual -n tekton-pipelines --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}'
```

[Here's also a full GitHub Actions pipeline run](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks/runs/4321961432?check_suite_focus=true) if you're interested.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have found this is only a partial solution because of the significant time delay between the load balancer’s URL becoming available and the web server actually starting.  

I am installing ArgoCD and the `argocd login` command fails because although the URL is available, the load balancer Web server has not started yet.

It's an ugly fix, but an `until curl` loop forces a delay until the Web Server responds with some HTML (which can take over a minute)

`until curl $ARGO_LB_URL | grep '<a href='; do : ; done`

Can anyone suggest a better solution?

Comment: I had exaclty the same problem with ArgoCD (in contrast to Traefik, where the solution described above worked fine): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71030112/4964553 As described in the answer with Argo I used `until argocd login $(kubectl get service argocd-server -n argocd --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}') --username admin --password $(kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d; echo) --insecure; do : ; done`.

Comment: Here's also my full GitHub Actions workflow with the exact line where I use the `until argocd login` command: https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks/blob/main/.github/workflows/provision.yml#L186 As I install Argo on a fresh AWS EKS cluster, this should work for you also?! Before the command I also run `until kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data}" | grep "password"; do : ; done`  to have the secret propagated correctly and `kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod -l app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-server -n argocd` to check the Argo pod is running.