# Wait for loadbalancer external IP using kubectl wait

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

How can I wait for a LoadBalancer service to have an external IP assigned? I found [a few stackoverlow questions relating to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114851/kubectl-wait-for-service-to-get-external-ip), but those were written before the kubectl wait command could wait for an arbitrary jsonpath.

From what I understand, the command would look something like this, however according to [the wait documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait), I need a JSONPath expression to compare against, and I don't know how to simply check if a field exists

I understand my command would look something like this

```
kubectl wait service/service-name --for=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'
```

However, i get the following error due to there being no condition specified:

```
error: jsonpath wait format must be --for=jsonpath='{.status.readyReplicas}'=3
```

I've tested it and it works if I put in a = with the current IP. How can I specify "any string" in the value?

```
$ kubectl wait --for=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'=127.0.0.1 service/my-service
service/my-service condition met
```

I've also tried other jsonPath's (which work in `kubectl get`) like `{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress[*]}{"Ready"}{end}` in an attempt to convert the IP to a string I can use for the equality check, but I get an `unexpected path string` when using it with `kubectl wait`

Or is there a better way to wait for this service to be ready to get the IP? I'm deploying to GKE from Github Actions

Comment: I have not tried, so only asking did `kubectl wait --for=condition=ready .....` is of any help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179410/how-to-wait-until-kubernetes-assigned-an-external-ip-to-a-loadbalancer-service

Comment: @gohm'c The answer in that question mentions that it isn't possible until jsonpath becomes supported and links a PR, but that PR is now merged and jsonpath is supported. I don't have the reputation to comment to ask for that question to be updated sadly

Comment: @P.... That's what I've been trying, albeit replacing the condition for a JSON path. The problem is, LoadBalancer services don't have any status fields we can watch for, so we need to use JSONPath to select a different field. And we have to use an = for a conditional which compares string equality. Problem is, I don't know what the IP is, so it's impossible to compare the values

Comment: you can check this [wait until kubernetes assigned an external ip to a loadbalancer service](https://codehunter.cc/a/kubernetes/how-to-wait-until-kubernetes-assigned-an-external-ip-to-a-loadbalancer-service)

Comment: That might work, but is there no way to do it with the built in kubectl wait tool? It feels like it was designed for this

Comment: upon further searching from [kubectl wait unable to not wait for service](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/80828#issuecomment-979054581) you can use [until kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70108499/kubectl-wait-for-service-on-aws-eks-to-expose-elastic-load-balancer-elb-addres/70108500#70108500) as an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes sadly also after the release of K8s 1.23 incl. the [mentioned PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/105776) it doesn't seem to be possible to use `kubectl wait` for the Ingress IP to show up (which means that the loadbalancer got deployed asynchronously by your cloud provider). If you need a one-liner, there's [`until kubectl get service/<service-name> --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done`mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70109667/4964553).

Comment: See also [this comment in the PR for arbitrary jsonpath in kubectl wait](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83094#issuecomment-1464809824).