# Kubectl wait for service to get external ip

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to use kubectl to wait for a service to get an external ip assigned. I've been trying to use the below just to get started

```
kubectl wait --for='jsonpath={.spec.externalTrafficPolicy==Cluster}' --timeout=30s --namespace cloud-endpoints svc/esp-echo
```

But I keep getting the below error message

```
error: unrecognized condition: "jsonpath={.spec.externalTrafficPolicy==Cluster}"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to pass arbitrary `jsonpath` and there is already a [request for the feature](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83094).

However, you can use a bash script with some sleep and monitor the service using other `kubectl` commands:

```
kubectl get --namespace cloud-endpoints svc/esp-echo --template="{{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress}}{{.ip}}{{end}}"
```

The above command will return the external IP for the LoadBalancer service for example.

You can write a simple bash file using the above as:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=""
while [ -z $ip ]; do
  echo "Waiting for external IP"
  ip=$(kubectl get svc $1 --namespace cloud-endpoints --template="{{range .status.loadBalancer.ingress}}{{.ip}}{{end}}")
  [ -z "$ip" ] && sleep 10
done
echo 'Found external IP: '$ip
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated from [Krishna Chaurasia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5147259/krishna-chaurasia)'s answer, `kubectl` have implemented the feature to be able to wait on arbitrary `jsonpath` value now. 
However, the catch is the value will only be [primitive value, excluding nested primitive value (`map[string]interface{}` or `[]interface{}`)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/8f91d09865b7adb641a5e890d8b9b6053078b81a/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/wait/wait.go#L620-L623)

Answer (score 1):

Right now `kubectl wait` [doesn't seem to work for in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73695734/4964553) (see also [this PR's comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83094#issuecomment-1464809824)). Meanwhile you can do this:

```
until kubectl get svc/esp-echo --namespace cloud-endpoints --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done
```

or even enhance the command [using timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58759974/4964553) ([`brew install coreutils` on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70109348/4964553)) to prevent the command from running infinitely:

```
timeout 10s bash -c 'until kubectl get service/tekton-dashboard-external-svc-manual -n tekton-pipelines --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done'
```

[We the same problem on AWS EKS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108500/4964553), where a AWS Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) gets provisioned when one creates a `Service` with the type `LoadBalancer`. That's most likely comparable to other cloud providers behaviour since [it's part of the official kubernetes.io docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer):

> On cloud providers which support external load balancers, setting the
> type field to LoadBalancer provisions a load balancer for your
> Service. The actual creation of the load balancer happens
> asynchronously, and information about the provisioned balancer is
> published in the Service's `.status.loadBalancer` field.

Krishna Chaurasia's answer also used this field, but we wanted to have a one-liner which could be used without extra bash script just like a `kubectl wait`. So our solution incorporates the solution stated on serverfault about ["watching" the output of a command until a particular string is observed and then exit](https://superuser.com/a/375331/497608) with using the `until` loop.

Comment: Can you show how to do kubectl wait for a service with jsonpath?

Comment: The answer already contains jsonpath like this `--output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a condition. Like:

`kubectl -n foobar wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=32s foo/bar`

Here is a good article that explains that: https://mrkaran.dev/posts/kubectl-wait/

In your case, you might use one of the [k8s probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).

Comment: Right now in current Kubernetes versions `kubectl wait` isn't usable for this problem (as stated in the issues [kubectl wait unable to not wait for service ready #80828](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/80828#issuecomment-517555879) & [kubectl wait on arbitrary jsonpath #83094](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/80828). Only from Kubernetes `v1.23` on (see [this merged PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/105776)) using jsonpath together with `kubectl wait` will be possible.

Comment: The main reason is, that `kubectl wait` assumes that the `status` field of a Kubernetes resource queried with `kubectl get service/xyz --output=yaml` contains a `conditions` list. [Which a `Service` doesn't have](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/80828#issuecomment-517555879). So in your `kubectl wait` command the `condition=complete` will never be reached, since there are no conditions in Services.