# How to login to ArgoCD CLI non-interactive in CI like GitHub Actions?

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, continuous-deployment, amazon-eks, argocd

We have [a full-blown setup using AWS EKS with Tekton](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks) installed and want to use ArgoCD for application deployment.

[As the docs state](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/) we installed ArgoCD on EKS in GitHub Actions with:

```
  - name: Install ArgoCD
    run: |
      echo "--- Create argo namespace and install it"
      kubectl create namespace argocd --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
      kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml
```

We also exposed the ArgoCD server (incl. dashboard) [as the docs told us](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/#3-access-the-argo-cd-api-server):

```
  - name: Expose ArgoCD Dashboard
    run: |
      echo "--- Expose ArgoCD Dashboard via K8s Service"
      kubectl patch svc argocd-server -n argocd -p '{"spec": {"type": "LoadBalancer"}}'

      echo "--- Wait until Loadbalancer url is present (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108500/4964553)"
      until kubectl get service/argocd-server -n argocd --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' | grep "ingress"; do : ; done
```

Finally we installed `argocd` CLI with brew:

```
      echo "--- Install ArgoCD CLI"
      brew install argocd
```

Now how can we do a `argocd login` with GitHub Actions (without human interaction)? The `argocd login` command wants a username and password...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The same docs tell us how to extract the password](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/#4-login-using-the-cli) for argo with:

```
kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d; echo
```

Obtaining the ArgoCD server's `hostname` is also no big deal using:

```
kubectl get service argocd-server -n argocd --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}'
```

And as the `argocd login` command has the parameters `--username` and `--password`, **we can craft our login command like this**:

```
argocd login $(kubectl get service argocd-server -n argocd --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}') --username admin --password $(kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d; echo) --insecure
```

Mind the `--insecure` to prevent the argo CLI from asking things like `WARNING: server certificate had error: x509: certificate is valid for localhost, argocd-server, argocd-server.argocd, argocd-server.argocd.svc, argocd-server.argocd.svc.cluster.local, not a5f715808162c48c1af54069ba37db0e-1371850981.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com. Proceed insecurely (y/n)?`.

The successful login should somehow look like this in the GitHub Actions UI (see [a full log here](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks/runs/5105912670?check_suite_focus=true)):

```
'admin:login' logged in successfully
Context 'a5f715808162c48c1af54069ba37db0e-1371850981.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com' updated
```

Now your GitHub Actions workflow should be able to interact with the ArgoCD server.

### Prevent error `FATA[0000] dial tcp: lookup a965bfb530e8449f5a355f221b2fd107-598531793.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host`

This error arises if the `argocd-server` Kubernetes service is freshly installed right before the `argocd login` command is run. Then the `argocd login` command failes for some time until it finally will work correctly.

Assuming some DNS propagation issues we can prevent this error from breaking our CI pipeline by wrapping our `argocd login` command into an `until` like already done [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108997/4964553). The full command will then look like this:

```sh
until argocd login $(kubectl get service argocd-server -n argocd --output=jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}') --username admin --password $(kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d; echo) --insecure; do : ; done
```

In GitHub Actions this will then look somehow like this:

```
--- Login argocd CLI - now wrapped in until to prevent FATA[0000] dial tcp: lookup 12345.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
time="2022-02-21T12:57:32Z" level=fatal msg="dial tcp: lookup a071bed7e9ea14747951b04360133141-459093397.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host"
time="2022-02-21T12:57:35Z" level=fatal msg="dial tcp: lookup a071bed7e9ea14747951b04360133141-459093397.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host"
time="2022-02-21T12:57:37Z" level=fatal msg="dial tcp: lookup a071bed7e9ea14747951b04360133141-459093397.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host"
[...]
time="2022-02-21T12:58:27Z" level=fatal msg="dial tcp: lookup a071bed7e9ea14747951b04360133141-459093397.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host"
time="2022-02-21T12:58:30Z" level=fatal msg="dial tcp: lookup a071bed7e9ea14747951b04360133141-459093397.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host"
time="2022-02-21T12:58:32Z" level=fatal msg="dial tcp: lookup a071bed7e9ea14747951b04360133141-459093397.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host"
'admin:login' logged in successfully
Context 'a071bed7e9ea14747951b04360133141-459093397.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com' updated
```

[Here's also a log](https://github.com/jonashackt/tekton-argocd-eks/runs/5274400263?check_suite_focus=true).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can exec to running argocd-server kubernetes pod:

```
kubectl exec -it argocd-server-669c567686-886np -n argocd -- /bin/bash
```

Your pod name will be different due to the hash at the end. Then login to the local argocd using:

```
argocd login localhost:8080 --insecure
```

it will prompt you for a username and password. If this is your first login you can find the initial password in the secret

```
kubectl -n argocd get secret argocd-initial-admin-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 -d; echo
```