# In idiomatic Bash with the AWS CLI, how would one 'create' an AWS resource and then 'wait' (get-/describe-) said resource for a given state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cloud9

I want to understand the idiomatic Bash (ie the Bash equivalent of '[Pythonic](https://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html)') way with the AWS CLI to create an AWS resource (say an AWS Cloud9 EC2 environment) and then 'poll'/'wait'/'sleep' for that resource to reach a certain state; when the AWS resources reaches the given state, the command completes and the user is able to enter commands back into the shell.

EG after the user hits Enter

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-10-10-10 ~]$ #an idiomatic Bash one-liner that combines 'aws cloud9 create-environment-ec2 --name this-resource-will-take-a-moment-to-create --instance-type t2.micro' and 'aws cloud9 describe-environments --environment-ids tHiSiDwAsThEoUtPuToFtHePrEvIoUsCoMmAnD'
```

Then after some time the user will see

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-10-10-10 ~]$ #an idiomatic Bash one-liner that combines 'aws cloud9 create-environment-ec2 --name this-resource-will-take-a-moment-to-create --instance-type t2.micro' and 'aws cloud9 describe-environments --environment-ids tHiSiDwAsThEoUtPuToFtHePrEvIoUsCoMmAnD'
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-10-10-10 ~]$
```

at which point the AWS Cloud9 EC2 environment has reached a given state.

As the create(create-,launch-, etc)/wait(get-/describe-) pattern is common among AWS services API calls and then corresponding AWS CLI commands the one-liner should be re-usable given minor changes for other services.

The Bash one-liner will be used in the CloudShell but should be portable to be used in other installations of Bash.

I have read about `&&` and `sleep` but would like some direction as to how to integrate these commands (or any alternative ones) in a idiomatic Bash one-liner.  Also I am concerned about not violating any throttling or request limiting AWS APIs have.

Comment: You might consider writing a Python script using boto3 Waiters (see [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html)).

Comment: I'll investigate Boto3 waiters (not only for this project but for others), thanks.  But I'd like to focus on the AWS CLI as I plan on instructing a non-technical user/customer to issue these commands in a AWS CloudShell (the Cloud9 EC2 environment is where I could ask the user to write and execute Python code), possibly over the phone or email.  There is also the issue of Boto/PyPi version, where the script will be created from and saved, how many characters the Python script will be compared to a one-liner, etc.  With the AWS CloudShell the only requirements would be Bash and the AWS CLI.

Comment: One generic pattern in bash (awscli aside) is: `until some-command-here; do sleep 5; done`. Other ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321469/retry-a-bash-command-with-timeout). Example for testing with: `until test -f /tmp/fred; do sleep 5; done` and then in another shell run `echo > /tmp/fred`. Maybe you can combine this pattern with aws list/describe commands.

Answer (score 0):

As [jarmod commented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74826164/18646223) with 'boto3 Waiters', I looked more into the [AWS CLI's Github Issues](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues?page=2&q=poll) and found this [Issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/895)

> The underlying library that powers the CLI, botocore, has this capability already via a concept it calls "waiters", which is a data driven way to describe waiting for a resource to reach a certain state... We just need to come up with a suitable API to expose this in the CLI.

The [capability](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/895#issuecomment-200525230) was implemented in [aws-cli](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cli-user-guide/blob/main/doc_source/cli-usage-commandstructure.md#cli-usage-commandstructure-wait) but [each service](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/wait/index.html) has to then use that capability for [their own service](https://www.google.com/search?q=aws%20cli%20wait).

It looks at the time of this writing the Cloud9 part of the aws-cli does not support [wait](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloud9/index.html).