# Elegant solution to implement timeout for bash commands and functions

Tags: bash

I wrote a function to run commands, which takes two args 1st a command 2nd timeout in seconds:

```
#! /bin/bash

function run_cmd {
    cmd="$1"; timeout="$2"
    grep -qP "^\d+$" <<< "$timeout" || timeout=10

    stderrfile=$(readlink /proc/$$/fd/2)
    exec 2<&-

    exitfile=/tmp/exit_$(date +%s.%N)
    (eval "$cmd";echo $? > $exitfile) &

    start=$(date +%s)
    while true; do
        pid=$(jobs -l | awk '/Running/{print $2}')
        if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
            now=$(date +%s)
            running=$(($now - $start))
            if [ "$running" -ge "$timeout" ];then
                kill -15 "$pid"
                exit=1
            fi
            sleep 1
        else
            break
        fi

    done 
    test -n "$exit" || exit=$(cat $exitfile)
    rm $exitfile
    exec 2>$stderrfile              
    return "$exit"
}


function sleep5 {
    sleep 5
    echo "I slept 5"
    return 2
}

run_cmd sleep5 "6" 
run_cmd sleep5 "3"
echo "hi" >&2
```

The function works fine but I am not sure it's an elegant solution, I would like to know about alternatives for the following

1. I am having to store exit status on a file: `(eval "$cmd";echo $?   > $exitfile)`
2. I am closing and reopening STDERR:  `exec 2<&- and exec 2>$stderrfile`

I am closing STDERR because I couldn't avoid the message when killing the command:

`test.sh: line 3: 32323 Terminated              ( eval "$cmd"; echo $? > $exitfile )`

PS: I am aware of `timeout` and `expect` but they wouldn't work for functions.

Comment: Whats the full purpose of the script.

Comment: @Jidder the purpose is to be able to timeout commands and functions, but exit status is very important as I will be implementing a retry function as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps this suits your needs. I changed the call signature to make it possible to avoid using `eval`.

```
# Usage: run_with_timeout N cmd args...
#    or: run_with_timeout cmd args...
# In the second case, cmd cannot be a number and the timeout will be 10 seconds.
run_with_timeout () { 
    local time=10
    if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then time=$1; shift; fi
    # Run in a subshell to avoid job control messages
    ( "$@" &
      child=$!
      # Avoid default notification in non-interactive shell for SIGTERM
      trap -- "" SIGTERM
      ( sleep $time
        kill $child 2> /dev/null ) &
      wait $child
    )
}
```

Example, showing exit status:

```
$ sleep_and_exit() { sleep ${1:-1}; exit ${2:-0}; }

$ time run_with_timeout 1 sleep_and_exit 3 0; echo $?

real    0m1.007s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.006s
143

$ time run_with_timeout 3 sleep_and_exit 1 0; echo $?

real    0m1.007s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.008s
0

$ time run_with_timeout 3 sleep_and_exit 1 7; echo $?

real    0m1.006s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.006s
7
```

As shown, the exit status of `run_with_timeout` will be the exit status of the executed command unless it was killed by the timeout, in which case it will be 143 (128 + 15).

Note: If you set a large timeout and/or have a forkbomb running, you might recycle pids fast enough that the kill-child kills the wrong process.

Comment: +1 I like the approach, but I still get: `test3.sh: line 9: 14075 Terminated              "$@"`

Comment: @Tiago: The runs I show in the example are exactly as they appear on my terminal. What shell are you using? Also: Did you copy it into a script instead of leaving  it as a function?

Comment: try run_with_timeout with a function like `sleep5` from my script.

Comment: @Tiago: I used exactly your `sleep5` and got the same result, as expected.

Comment: that's odd I don't know what's the problem, take a look @ http://paste.ubuntu.com/7701295/

Comment: If I source the functions and run in the current shell as you did it works, but If I add the function to the script it doesn't

Comment: @Tiago: must have something to do with the non-interactive shell in that case. Checking...

Comment: @Tiago: See edited answer. See line 3530 of jobs.c (approx): `if (interactive_shell == 0 && termsig && WIFSIGNALED (s) && termsig != SIGINT && signal_is_trapped (termsig) == 0) { /* print notification */ }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56289/discussion-between-rici-and-tiago).

Comment: @rici please read my answer, instead of `sleep 3600` I would split the seconds into smaller pieces like this: `start=$SECONDS; while [ "$((SECONDS-start))" -lt "3600" ] && kill -0 $child; do sleep 1; done`.

Comment: @lx42.de: There is no need. The outer `(...)` will terminate as soon as the `wait` finishes whether because the process started as `"$@"` has terminated or because it was killed by the `kill` after the `sleep`. As soon as the outer `(...)` terminates, the inner `(...)` will be terminated, even if it is still sleeping because the sleep was longer than the execution time. You're correct that `kill -KILL` would be more definitive, but `kill -TERM` (the default signal) is better if you need to do some clean up in a TERM handler.

Comment: @rici Thank you for your details. I would do the SIGKILL a few seconds AFTER the SIGTERM, if the process does not react on that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control functions, you may use a trap handler (like in C)

```
$ trap 'break' 15
$ echo $$; while :; do :; done; echo 'endlessloop terminated'
5168
endlessloop terminated
$
```

If you type `kill -15 5168` in another shell, the program interrupts and prints `endlessloop terminated`

If you are spawning a subprocess, please take care about four additional things

1. if the subprocess ends long before the sleep, it results in a long sleep process.
   So it is better to keep the sleep short and keep on checking multiple times. For example, it is better to do 360 sleeps of 10s than to sleep 3600s = 1hour. Because the sleep may fill up your process table up to the limit. (Or you have to kill the sleep as soon as the $cmd finishes.)
2. if the process does not react on a normal kill, you may want to add an additional `kill -9` a few seconds afterwards.
3. if you need the return value of the process, then you have to extend you program using a wrapper, which delivers the return value to a file/fifo.
4. if you need the stdout/stderr output of the process, ... file/fifo.

All these things are covered by the C program timelimit.

http://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/

```
$ timelimit
timelimit: using defaults: warntime=3600, warnsig=15, killtime=120, killsig=9
timelimit: usage: timelimit [-pq] [-S ksig] [-s wsig] [-T ktime] [-t wtime] command
```

This program has a few benefits:

- it checks, if the process is still running and has not exited while sleeping for kill
- if sends a soft killsignal first and a hard -9 signal if this does not work
- it propagates (Option -p) the returnlevel ($?) so you may use it for your purpose.

Comment: I am suprised of your comment, because you flagged the answer of rici as the correct answer. Ok, let me write a few words to extend my answer.

Comment: I accepted Rici as correct answer 5 months ago :) +1 for your efforts though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've got a elegant solution based on @rici answer (which I accepted), and decided I would share the end result, I also added a retry function which was the real goal.

```
function run_cmd { 
    cmd="$1"; timeout="$2";
    grep -qP '^\d+$' <<< $timeout || timeout=10

    ( 
        eval "$cmd" &
        child=$!
        trap -- "" SIGTERM 
        (       
                sleep $timeout
                kill $child 
        ) > /dev/null 2>&1 &     
        wait $child
    )
}

function retry { 
        cmd=$1; timeout=$2; tries=$3; interval=$4
        grep -qP '^\d+$' <<< $timeout || timeout=10
        grep -qP '^\d+$' <<< $tries || tries=3 
        grep -qP '^\d+$' <<< $interval || interval=3
        for ((c=1; c <= $tries; c++)); do
                run_cmd "$cmd" "$timeout" && return
                sleep $interval
        done    
        return 1
}
```

The retry function accepts 4 args:

1. The command
2. Timeout
3. Attempts
4. Interval

It can be executed as below:

`retry "some_command_or_function arg1 arg2 .." 5 2 10`

Comment: Would you use this function instead of the greps?

isint () { [ "$1" != "" -a "${1//[0-9-]}" = "" ]; }

Comment: (+@lx42.de) A more efficient, if perhaps less readable alternative: `timeout=${2:-10};timeout=${timeout/*[^[:digit:]]*/10}`. The glob (`*[^[:digit:]]*/`) matches the entirety of any string which contains a non-digit, so the replacement with 10 (`/10`) happens exactly if the value of `$2` has a non-digit. The first `{2:-10}` is necessary to insert `10` as a default value. Personally, I prefer signalling an error for invalid values, but YMMV.