# Execute a timed function in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to implement a timed function. If the timer times out the function/command should be killed. If the function/command finishes, the timer should not make the bash to wait for the timer to timeout.

```
(cmdpid=$BASHPID; \
    ( sleep 60; kill $cmdpid 2>/dev/null) &  \
    child_pid=$!; \
    ssh remote_host /users/jj/test.sh; \
    kill -9 $child_pid)
```

The test.sh may or may not finish in 60 seconds. This worked fine.

But when I want to get the result of the test.sh, which echoes "SUCESS" or "FAILURE", I tried with

```
result=$(cmdpid=$BASHPID; \
    ( sleep 60; kill $cmdpid 2>/dev/null) &  \
    child_pid=$!; \
    ssh remote_host /users/jj/test.sh; \
    kill -9 $child_pid)
```

Here it waits for timer to exit. I can see the "kill -9 $child_pid" is executed, using set -x command, but the kill is not really killing the sub-shell.

Comment: What sub-shell do you talk about? If the `sleep` is finished, the `kill $cmdpid` would kill the first subshell... if that is possible using just a QUIT signal (I'm not sure). My doubt: can a subshell be killed using a QUIT signal if any of its child processes is hanged?

Comment: The problem is that you are killing the subshell, not the `sleep` within it.  If you look in a `ps` you will see that the `sleep`'s  parent pid is 0.

Comment: Are you aware of the `timeout` command? I seems like you're trying to reinvent the wheel....

Comment: Using `timeout` is convenient, but it would not kill independent child processes started by the script with calls like (for example) `nohup /folder/OtherScript &`. By putting the timer in a separate script, one could customize the timer and kill even such independent child processes.

Comment: @cdarke: You are correct. The inner sub-shell is killed, but the sleep remains. But the PID of sleep is not 0, but $child_pid+1.  A little bit of google told me that when the a process is killed, only its direct child is signaled. But since I am killing the sleep's parent, the new parent is 1.

Comment: Perhaps this question/answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412721/elegant-solution-to-implement-timeout-for-bash-commands-and-functions/24413646#24413646

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the parent pid is 1, the 0 was a typo.  You cannot assume that the PID of `sleep` is always $child_pid + 1, it will depend on other processes within the system being created.  You can't even assume that the PID is greater than $child_pid.

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle this problem would be to run the timer on a separate script, say `MyTimerTest`, which is called from the (say) `MainScriptTest` but runs separately, and then whichever script that finishes first "kills" the other. For example:

On `MainScriptTest` you could put this at the beginning:

```
nohup /folder/MyTimerTest > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

On `MainScriptTest` you could put this at the very end:

```
killall MyTimerTest > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The `MyTimerTest` could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 60
killall MainScriptTest > /dev/null 2>&1
exit 0
```

Note: the long name for the scripts with mixed capital and lowercase letters (ex.: `MainScriptTest`) is on purpose, `killall` is case sensitive and that helps to preclude it from killing something it should not. To be very safe, you might want to even add a token in addition to the longer name, like:  `MainScriptTest88888` or something like that.

**Edit:** Thanks to `gilez`, who suggested the use of the `timeout` command. If that is available to you on your system, one could do a quick one-liner like this:

```
timeout 60 bash -c "/folder/MainScriptTest"
```

Using `timeout` is convenient. However, if `MainScriptTest` creates independent child processes (for example by calling: `nohup /folder/OtherScript &`) then `timeout` would not kill those child processes, and the exit would not be clean.

The first solution I gave is longer, but it could be customized to kill those child processes (or any other processes you want) by adding them to the `MainScriptTest`, like for example:

```
killall OtherScript > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: This did not work. The sleep running from the new bash script assumes the name "sleep" and killall could not find it

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem on my systems - here it works perfectly. I have `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)`. I am not sure also that I understand what you say the problem was. Was `sleep` alone that continued to run? What about `MainScriptTest` and `MyTimerTest`, do they get killed? Again, please elaborate if you want to investigate this -- I would like to if you're willing, it would be interesting and possibly instructive to do so.

Comment: When I tried the way you mentioned, "ps" was showing "sleep" instead of "MyTimerTest". So I was not able to kill the script using "killall MyTimerTest". The bash I am using is 4.1.2(1). Unfortunately I cannot upgrade it.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not making sense to me. Why did you mentioned `ps`? That is not necessary at all with `killall`, nor was that on my code. Also, If `ps aux | grep MyTimerTest | grep -v "grep MyTimerTest"` does not show anything, then `MyTimerTest` is already not running. Remember, `MyTimerTest` exits after 60 seconds.

Comment: I was trying to debug it. The issue I see is that even if the MainScriptTest is done with its job and exited, I was not getting the prompt back. So  using another shell, I tried to see what all processes were running. This was with in 60 second and I expected MyTimerTest would be running. But what I saw in the "ps" is a sleep, but not MyTimerTest.  Since killall is trying to kill the process by the name MyTimterTest, it was not able to.

Comment: Oh, I see. That code was written to run on a script, not on the terminal. On the terminal, the use of  nohup can hold up the terminal and you won't get the prompt back. And it will create a file nohup.out somewhere. If you put the code on the script that would not happen. I made the code like that because your question mentioned the script. But the code should still work correctly, except for the terminal issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found some other way.

```
result=$( ssh $remote_host /users/jj/test.sh ) & mypid=$!
( sleep 10; kill -9 $mypid ) &
wait $mypid
```