# Is there a way to source bash script inside other sourced script

Tags: linux, bash

My issue is following:
I've got my library (let's call it `qa-baslib.sh`) with various util functions, that I'm including it test scripts, we're developing.

Now, other developer created bash script library to support SSH connection to various servers (let's call it `global_ssh`). It looks something like:

`global_ssh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

global_ssh(){

   # Doing some ssh stuff
}
```

I'm sourcing that `global-ssh` file like that:

`qa-baslib.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

 . /<path-to>/qa-util-scripts/global_ssh

function some_util_function() {
   server=$1
   command=$2

   # Here i'm calling global_ssh function
   timeout -s 9 30 global_ssh $sever $command
}
```

But when I finally executing the function, by sourcing it from command line, I got error:

```
]# . /<path-to>/qa-bashlib.sh
]# some_util_function $server $command
]# timeout: failed to run command `global_ssh': No such file or directory
```

What's wrong and is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Is the shebang in script #1 a typo or the cause?

Comment: @frlan Sorry, fixed :)

Comment: Are you sure that your system's `timeout` can run a shell function? (What does `type timeout` print?) **Edited to add:** See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954794/execute-function-with-timeout.

Comment: @ruakh `/sbin/timeout`. Thanks man, it the exact point! previously there was just `ssh` so  `timeout -s 9 30 ssh` was valid, but when I replaced `ssh` by function I should've remove the timeout as well :)

Answer (score 1):

As @ruakh mentioned, `timeout` can't run with bash function as an argument.

Full answer:
[execute function with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954794/execute-function-with-timeout)