# Bash: run command for a certain amount of time and get its output

Tags: bash, command-line, command, timeout, strace

So I am trying to run a script that will capture the output of the command:

```
 echo 'password' | sudo -S strace -p14750 -s9999 -e write
```

for about 5 seconds and then store the output into a variable.
How can I do this?

Full script:

```
    appium_pid_output=$(echo 'password' | sudo -S strace -p$appium_device_pid -s9999 -e write)
    echo 'captured output of node '$appium_pid_output

    if [[ $appium_pid_output == *POST* ]]; then
        echo "device [ " + $device + " ] is currently in use"
        return 1
    fi
```

Comment: Would be nice to have some feedback. Any problems with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `timeout` command.

```
var="$(timeout 5 whateverProducesTheOutput)"
```

A drawback is that timeout doesn't work well with complex commands. The easiest way around this is to write a function and execute the function with a timeout (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31311722/6770384)).

```
foo() {
    whateverProducesTheOutput
}
export -f foo
var="$(timeout 5 bash -c foo)"
```