# Bash: how to check if a command executed in time

Tags: linux, bash, conditional-statements

I am trying to execute this command `expressvpn connect` in a bash script to be executed in terminal. The problem is that sometimes it takes too long to connect and I want to make sure it doesn't take too much. I tried this command

```
some_command
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
fi
```

but this is for checking wether the command is executed or not, while I want to make sure that if it is not executed in, say 10 seconds, then the script must stop and start over from the beginning. How do I do that?
Here's the full code

```
#!/bin/bash

expressvpn disconnect 

while (0<1); do
    expressvpn connect smart location
    xdg-open http://link 
    sleep 15 
    xdotool key Control_L+w  
    expressvpn disconnect  
    expressvpn refresh
done
```

I hope I was clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954794/execute-function-with-timeout

Comment: right! I can use timeout. I didn't think about that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I hope you find it useful.

```
timeout 15s expressvpn connect smart location>/dev/null &
```

Comment: but this checks if the command is executed, while I want to give my command a timeout

Comment: You need remove background "&". Otherwise $? is a non sense

Comment: Yes, you're right, but better without the checking since @mfjoe only needs the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply execute this :

```
 timeout 15s expressvpn connect smart location

 case "$?" in
     0)   echo "OK"      ;;
     124) echo "TIMEOUT" ;;
     *)   echo "FAIL"    ;;
 esac
```

from [man timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html)

Exit status:

- 124 if command times out
- 125 if timeout itself fails
- 126 if command is found but cannot be invoked
- 127 if command cannot be found
- 137 if command is sent the KILL(9) signal (128+9)

Comment: It works as long as I use one "case", but when I use two of them it gives me this error `/typert: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./typert: line 25: `          124) echo "EXPRESSVPN TIMEOUT" ;;'
`. Is that because of that value? 124? I tried the debug and this error happens when executing the second case. So one case it's fine but how can I use two?