# How to timeout complex processes in bash?(process with child-processes of its own)

Tags: bash, timeout, child-process, terminate, subshell

The process in context here is 'android build environment'.
To timeout normal tasks, one would do

```
#Timeout command 'do_task' in 10 seconds
timeout 10s do_task
```

However, when I try the same with android build environment, it doesn't seem to work.
This is what happens instead:

```
box@boxputer:/media/box/backup/cr81x$ source build/envsetup.sh
box@boxputer:/media/box/backup/cr81x$ lunch aosp_arm-eng
Trying dependencies-only mode on a non-existing device tree?

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=12
TARGET_DEVICE=generic
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.13.0-44-generic-x86_64-Zorin-OS-16.1
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=SQ3A.220605.009.A1
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=device/generic/goldfish device/generic/goldfish-opengl hardware/google/camera hardware/google/camera/devices/EmulatedCamera device/generic/goldfish device/generic/goldfish-opengl
============================================
box@boxputer:/media/box/backup/cr81x$ timeout 10s mka bacon
timeout: failed to run command ‘mka’: No such file or directory
```

Here, 'mka bacon' is the build command, 'make' or 'm' could also be used, but they all result in the same error as mentioned above.

What I've tried additionally includes

```
# Spawn a child process:
(dosmth) & pid=$!
# in the background, sleep for 10 secs then kill that process
(sleep 10 && kill -9 $pid) &
```

```
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; 
    (sleep 10; kill $cmdpid) \
   & while ! ping -w 1 www.goooooogle.com 
     do 
         echo crap; 
     done )
```

and other answers from [This Particular Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/how-to-kill-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout-in-bash).

I've also tried another solution on a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954794/execute-a-shell-function-with-timeout)

while one gave me success, it introduced a problem of its own(code below)

```
mka bacon &
sleep 10s
```

This however ensures that the process isn't terminated until 10 seconds have passed.
Say I finish the build in 5 seconds. The process still won't exit. It won't exit till 10 seconds have passed, which isn't a desirable situation when a build produces an error.

And when I try the other answers from [This Particular Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/how-to-kill-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout-in-bash), The process terminates after 10 seconds, but the entire terminal glitches, and the build still runs(**at this stage even Ctrl+C doesn't work**)
My guess is that the build environment spawns its own child-processes with different PID's for the build?

If incase you're wondering what envsetup.sh is, [Here's its paste](https://pastebin.com/raw/QCkn1uyc)

Comment: what does `which mka` outputs (after loading the environment)?

Comment: ```which mka``` outputs nothing, as it's not a binary. Its loaded when I execute ```source build/envsetup.sh```. Its more of a function I suppose.

Comment: what's the output of `type mka` ?

Comment: You can find out *exactly* what it is by running `command -v mka` or `type mka`.

Comment: If `mka` is a function then you need to `export -f mka` and run `timeout 10s bash -c 'mka bacon'`

Comment: ```export -f mka``` returns the error ```export: invalid option(s) ```
I've attached the file too(envsetup.sh) https://katb.in/ajufewufowa

Comment: This error means that you're not running bash as your shell. Where's `mka` defined in envsetup.sh? I can't see it

Comment: @fravadona yes, I wasn't using bash. It was zsh.
Regarding ```mka```, I'm a bit confused myself, but it seems an alias of ```m```. I've attached a snippet of my terminal below:
```box@boxputer:/media/box/backup/cr81x$ which mka
mka not found
box@boxputer:/media/box/backup/cr81x$ source build/envsetup.sh
ccache enabled and CCACHE_EXEC has been set to : /usr/bin/ccache
box@boxputer:/media/box/backup/cr81x$ which mka
mka () {
 m "$@"
}```
Perhaphs envsetup.sh sources more files? but I see no source command within it.

Comment: @fravadona your previous approach worked, although ```export -f mka``` didn't.
What I did was:
```timeout 10s bash -c "source build/envsetup.sh; lunch aosp_arm-eng; mka bacon"```
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Timeout needs a binary to execute.
Based on your hint

> Here, 'mka bacon' is the build command, 'make' or 'm' could also be used

I assume, that mka is just an alias or function. You can find out, what it is and does with `type mka`.
When you found it, use that instead as arguments for timeout.